# How to make console application available in microsoft teams group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created console application for upload download file and I want to work that console application in MS teams group. what is the best possible way

Answer (score 0):

To build apps for Microsoft Teams, please see documentation on [building apps for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview). There is detailed support for a variety of scenarios: bots, messaging extensions, webhooks depending on your use case.

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.